# Python parsing out BeautifulSoup findAll info

Tags: python

I've been trying to fix this web scraper for a while and still cannot find out how to parse out information from a findAll function. I am trying to web scrape Nasdaq right now, and each stock on Nasdaq has a table of stock info. The first part of the table, the text part, renders perfectly on my python. However, when I try to grab the information on the number side of the table, I get this:'\r\n                        120\r\n                    '. The number is in there but I can't figure out how to separate it from the other info. Here is the rest of my code if you are interested.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft'
uClient = ureq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"table-cell"})
bidask = containers[8]
bidasktitle = bidask.b.text

bidaskvalue = containers[9]
bidaskvaluetitle = bidaskvalue.text

yeartarget = containers[10]
yeartargettitle = yeartarget.b.text

yeartargetvalue = containers[11]
yeartargetvaluetitle = yeartargetvalue.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strip()` will help you more, e.g.:

```
yeartargetvaluetitle = yeartargetvalue.text.strip()
```

strip() is an very useful function when you deal with the data that you scrapy, about [strip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of regular expressions to filter out numbers from a string.

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string);
```